# Child theme's functions.php not being read (child theme's autoload.php not being run)

Tags: functions, child-theme

Our child theme's functions.php contains:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

However, the files that autoload.php loads are not being loaded, and a fatal error occurs. `'/vendor/autoload.php'` exists.

Nothing gets echoed or logged if we add an echo or an error_log() above this line.

Why would the child theme's `functions.php` not be loading?

The child theme is active.

Comment: What’s the fatal error?